# Java find second-leading digit in int

Tags: java

I am working on a Java problem in which I need to check if the second-leading digit of an int (ex: the '2' in 123, or the '8' in 58347) of any size is a particular digit (such as a '2' or a '5'), and then assign true to a Boolean, if it is that digit. I am trying to do the modulo/divisor method, but I am not able to extract the second-leading digit if the number is large.

I searched Stack Overflow, and found a very similar question. However, the solution for that question works if the number is hard-coded as being two digits. I know there is a way by converting int to String, and I tried that method successfully, but I need to use int/modulo/division method. I tried doing (n%100)/10; but it got me second-to-last digit (ex: the '7' in 4562374), not second-after-first digit.

```
// n is a number such as 123, or 25, or 52856.
while (n > 0) { 
int i=((n%10)/10);
if( (i==2)||(i==3) || (i==5)|| (i==7) )
{ secondDigit=true; }
else { secondDigit= false; } }
System.out.println(secondDigit);
```

Comment: The logic you have provided checks every digit in the number rather than only the second digit. Is this intentional?

Comment: @Compass, that is NOT intentional. The intent is to check second-leading digit only.

Comment: Please format your code correctly, never place code on a bracket like this `{secondDigit}`, this code is hard to read and has no proper indenting either.  Where the loop ends is deceptive as well.

Comment: @Nexevis, good advise. I will try my best to format code more clearly in the future.

Comment: Do you care about negative numbers or purely positive numbers?

Comment: @Avi, the number can be non-zero, either positive or negative.

Comment: So your example shows no effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just keep dividing by 10 until the number is < 100 then do modulo 10, example:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 58347;
    while (n >= 100) {
      n /= 10;
    }
    System.out.println(n % 10); // prints 8
  }
}
```

Comment: This fails for negative numbers, perhaps use absolute value?

Comment: @Nexevis this is just an example (I didn't handle the different digits part as well), if the OP wants to support negative numbers (which they didn't mention) they should expend this example into a full working solution to their HW ;)

Comment: Yeah he mentioned in a comment recently, but you are right he did not initially mention it.

Comment: To support negatives, simply add `n = Math.abs(n);` before the while loop.

Comment: @Avi true that! and I'm sure the OP will be able to handle it by themselves, as I responded to Nexevis, this is an example.

Comment: @alfasin No problem; it's just a note for others in future.

Comment: Be aware that if `n < 10`, then `n % 10` is the first and only digit of the original number, not the second digit, since there is no second digit. --- Also, didn't you mean `while (n >= 100)`?

Comment: @Andreas good catch - thanks! I fixed to <=. As for other edge-cases, I'll leave it to the OP to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Not certain about the efficiency of this method, however its easy to read.

```
Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Math.abs(initial_value)).charAt(1)+"")
```

However, you have to ensure that the number has more than 1 digit.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of repeatedly dividing the number you have until it's small enough for you to handle, how about finding out how big the number is so you only need to do a single division?

What I mean is that you should consider using logarithms to find out the magnitude of your number. Finding the base 10 logarithm of your number gets you its magnitude. For 100 the log_10 is 2, so you can do the following:

```
long magnitude = Math.log10(number);
long divisor = Math.pow(10, magnitude - 1);
long smallNumber = number / divisor;
int digit = smallNumber % 10;
```